# ajax post upload progress - client side only

Tags: javascript, ajax, progress

I have a form from which users can select 100s of files to upload to my server.

When submitting the form a post request is made to the server which may be 100s of MBs long. I would like the users see a progress bar to see how much they have uploaded.

My question is as follows: is there any way to achieve this in client side JS only? I would much prefer to do it without making a call to a jsp or php file on the server.

We can use ext.js but not jquery.

Many thanks, Hugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Standard HTML `<form>` uploads don't expose their upload progress to JavaScript, so upload progress scripts have to either:

1. Have some way to retrieve the status of an upload from the server, and check that periodically
2. Use a nonstandard method of submitting the upload, such as a Flash or Java application, or by chunking the upload in JavaScript

Some browsers (such as Google Chrome) will unobtrusively display the progress of a `<form>` upload (e.g, in the status bar), but many don't, and there's no way I'm aware of to retrieve that data from within the page.

Comment: Thats a real shame but thanks alot for the clarification. Unfortunatly for my project I am restricted to firefox 3.6 so I wont get the upload progress.